# Managing file permissions with npm OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, npm, chown

I am trying to install [this](https://github.com/datatypevoid/vulgar) MEAN application generator on my mac - OSX El Capitan v10.11.4. However, I get the following output:

> Checking permissions...
>
> Cloning branch master into destination folder:  eval
>
> git clone  --depth 1  -b master https://github.com/datatypevoid/vulgar.git "eval"
>
> /usr/local/bin/npm
>   There are 2 files in your ~/.npm owned by root
>   Please change the permissions by running - chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vulgar-cli/lib/install.js:84
>         throw err;

The command won't run if I use `sudo`. I get an error saying the command can't be run as the root user.

I have run `chown -R georgeedwards ~/.npm`, which ran without any error, but I still get the same result.

What should I do to avoid this issue?

Comment: As the author of this repo, I would like to know if you resolved this issue? I had the same problem posed by someone else to me this morning.

Comment: @datatype_void I am afraid I gave up :(

Comment: I encourage you to give it another shot and let me know if it is resolved. A lot has changed with the recent merge of my development builds.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing `npm's` default directory.

1. Make a directory for global installations:

   `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
3. Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

   `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
4. Back on the command line, update your system variables:

   `source ~/.profile`

I found this at

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem persists, on mac the following worked for me:

Run these steps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40717226/11302398

and then:

```
npm config get prefix

/Users/user_name/.npm-global

sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm

sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/user_name/.npm-global
```

open a new console and run:

```
npm doctor
```